# Reading a SQL variable from a Visual Studio project

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a third party database created by someone else for use in a third party application that is limited in its customisability (using Microsoft SQL Server) so I am trying to create a small Visual Basic application to update a single value, using a button click.

I have found how to update the value, but now I am trying to display the value on my form, but I'm not succeeding.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using sqlcon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\xxx;Initial Catalog=IpposnifDB240;Integrated Security=True")
            sqlcon.Open()
            Dim sqltext = "UPDATE newcount SET Count = Count + 1"
            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sqltext, sqlcon)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Count from newcount", sqlcon)
            Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader(1)
        End Using

    End Sub
```

I expect you can guess that the `ExecuteReader` does not return the string that I am looking for, how do I obtain a string from my SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `ExecuteScalar()` instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Modify your code like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using sqlcon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\xxx;Initial Catalog=IpposnifDB240;Integrated Security=True")
        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim sqltext = "UPDATE newcount SET [Count] = [Count] + 1"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sqltext, sqlcon)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT [Count] from newcount", sqlcon)
        Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Also btw, `Count` is a reserved word and might give you problems if you don't escape it with square brackets (see above).